# Proof that $\delta_0 \not\in C^0(\mathbb{ R}^n)$

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, continuity, distribution-theory

I'm doing a course in PDEs, and this has come up as a problem. I've attempted a proof, but I've run into the issue that according to the professor, the only property that may be used is the fact that $\langle \delta_0, \phi \rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \delta_0(x) \phi(x) dx = \phi(0)$.

The only hint he was willing to give was to assume that $\delta_0$ is $C^0(\mathbb{R}^N)$, and show a contradiction. The problem that I'm having is that from what I've been able to find, every property of continuous functions requires the concept of a norm, something which $d_0$ doesn't have.

From the tone of his answer, he made it sound as though using any concept of a norm is therefore unacceptable, even in the context of a proof by contradiction, but I don't see how it could even be possible to make a statement about continuity without having some notion of a norm.

This was my attempt at a proof (the definition of \delta_0 that I use here was given in class):
Assume by absurd that $\delta_0 \in C^0(\mathbb{R}^N)$. Then given that $
\delta_0 \equiv \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} f_\epsilon$, where 
\begin{equation}
    f_\epsilon(x) =\begin{cases}
0 \quad & x \not\in B_\epsilon(0)\\
\frac{1}{\epsilon} \quad & x \in B_\epsilon(0)
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
and $B_\epsilon(0)$ is a ball with radius $\epsilon$ centered at $x=\vec{0}$, and given
$\tilde{\epsilon}>0$, there exists $\tilde{\delta}>0$ such that $||x-y||<\tilde{\delta}$ in the Euclidean norm for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^N$ implies that $|\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}f_{\epsilon}(x) - \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}f_{\epsilon}(y)| < \tilde{\epsilon}$.

Take $y = \vec{0}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$\ $\vec{0}$. In such a case, $$||x-y||=||x-\vec{0}||=||x||<\tilde{\delta}$$ $$\implies |\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}f_{\epsilon}(x) - \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}f_{\epsilon}(\vec{0})|=|0 - \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{\epsilon}| = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{\epsilon} <\tilde{\epsilon}$$

But,  $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ is clearly unbounded. Thus, the assumption that $\delta_0 \in C^0(\mathbb{R}^N)$ leads to a contradiction, therefore $\delta_0 \not\in C^0(\mathbb{R}^N) $.

Comment: Seems fine if you're allowed to assume that definition of $\delta_0$ for the problem. I would only be careful to note that you are looking at $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ and not $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{\epsilon}$, which is not even defined. I would, however, try to prove the result using only the fact that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n }\delta_0(x) \phi(x) dx = \phi (0)$. That is, let the integral equation be the defining property of $\delta_0$ and show that no function in $C^0 (\mathbb{R}^n)$ can have this property.

Comment: We had a very similar problem in our PDE course but the question was to show that $\delta_0$ as a distribution is not regular, meaning there exists no function $f$ such that $ \delta_0(\varphi) = \varphi(0) =  \int f(x) \varphi(x)dx. $

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Your suggestion makes sense, and I've been trying to take that approach. It makes sense intuitively, but I'm not entirely sure how I would prove that assertion that no function in $C^0(\mathbb{R}^N)$ rigorously. Do you think approaching it from the perspective of the fundamental theorem of calculus would be appropriate, or is there some other property of the integral of continuous functions that I'm blanking on?

Comment: I don't know for sure. I would look up the fundamental lemma of the calculus of variations. This problem has that feel to it.

Answer (score 1):

$\delta_0 \in C^0(\mathbb{R}^n$) implies $\delta_0 \in L^2(B_1(0))$, where $B_1(0)$ denotes the ball of radius $1$ around the origin. This is true since any continuous function is bounded on a compact set and therefore 
$$
\int_{B_1(0)} |\delta_0(x)|^2 \; dx \leq \sup_{x\in \overline{B_1(0)}} |\delta_0(x)|^2 \mu(B_1(0)) \leq C^2  \mu(B_1(0)) < \infty
$$
Asssume $\delta_0 \in L^2(B_1(0))$. Then, 
$$
F: L^2(B_1(0)) \mapsto \mathbb{R},f \mapsto \int_{B_1(0)} \delta_0(x)f(x)
$$
defines a continuous, linear functional on $L^2(B_1(0))$ by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality ( $|F(f)|\leq ||\delta_0||_{L^2(B_1(0))}||f||_{L^2(B_1(0))}$). Consider the sequence 
$$
f_k(x)=\sqrt k e^{-k|x|^2}\mathbb{1}_{B_1(0))}(x)
$$
Then $f_k \to 0$ in $L^2(B_1(0))$ and hence our continous, linear functional should go to $0$, i.e. $F(f_k) \to 0$. But 
$$
F(f_k)=\int_{B_1(0)} \delta_0(x)f_k(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \delta_0(x)f_k(x)=\sqrt{k} \to \infty 
$$ 
Hence $\delta_0 \notin L^2(B_1(0))$ and therefore $\delta_0 \notin C^0(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: There is a gap: It is given that $\int\delta f=f(0)$. However, we
do not know if $\int_{B_{1}(0)}\delta f=f(0).$ Hence, it is false
that $F(f_{n})=f_{n}(0)$.

Comment: I modified the proof, should be fine now

Comment: This is still not OK because now your $f_n$ is not continuous. Hence $f_n\notin C^0(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Also, it is a bad idea to use the letter $n$ to denote your sequence
$(f_{n})$ because $n$ has been used to denote the dimension of the
Eucliean space $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: More explicitly, if $f$ is not continuous, there is no reason that $\int\delta f=f(0)$.

Comment: In the question asked he did not specify to which functions the dirac delta is "applied". It should be sufficient if $0$ is a point of continuity - which it is. Otherwise you could probably restrict it to a ball with radius $1/2$ and then find a suitable cutoff function.

Comment: It is explicitly stated that the only property that may be used is:
$\delta\in C^{0}$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\delta f=f(0)$
for any $f\in C^{0}$. Then, we need to arrive a contradiction based on that assumption. We are not allowed to assume more. For example,
``it should be sufficient if $0$ is a point of continuity''.

Comment: $\phi \in C^0$ (which is f in my example) was never assumed in the question

Comment: This is the fault of OP. He should state the problem rigorously, in the form of a proposition (just like what I did).

Answer (score 1):

You may rephrase it in the form of a proposition: There does not exist
$\phi\in C^{0}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\phi(x)f(x)dx=f(0)$
for all $f\in C^{0}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$.

Proof: Prove by contradiction. Suppose the contrary that there exists
$\phi\in C^{0}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\phi(x)f(x)dx=f(0)$
for all $f\in C^{0}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. To ease discussion, we only
consider the case that $n=1$. Firstly, we go to prove that $\phi(x)=0$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. Let $a\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$
be arbitrary. Choose $\delta>0$ such that $0\notin(a-\delta,a+\delta)$.
Choose $g\in C^{0}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $g\geq0$, $g(a)=1$, and
$g=0$ outside $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$. Note that $g$ exists. For
example, we may choose $g$ to be
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases}
0, & \mbox{if }x\leq a-\delta\\
\frac{1}{\delta}(x-a)+1, & \mbox{if }x\in(a-\delta,a]\\
-\frac{1}{\delta}(x-a)+1, & \mbox{if }x\in(a,a+\delta)\\
0, & \mbox{if }x\geq a+\delta
\end{cases}.
$$
Note that, in particular, we have $g(0)=0$. Define $f=\phi g\in C^{0}(\mathbb{R})$.
By assumption, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
0 & = & f(0)\\
 & = & \int\phi(x)f(x)dx\\
 & = & \int\phi^{2}(x)g(x)dx,
\end{eqnarray*}
which implies that $\phi(a)=0$ (because if $\phi(a)\neq0$, then
$\phi^{2}g\geq0$, $\phi^{2}g$ is continuous, and $(\phi^{2}g)(a)>0$
$\Rightarrow\int\phi^{2}g>0$).

By continuity of $\phi$, it follows that $\phi(0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\phi(x)=0$.
Hence, $\phi(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, for any
$f\in C^{0}(\mathbb{R})$, $f(0)=\int\phi f=0$, which is obviously
a contradiction.

For the general case that $n>1$, the above proof continues to hold except that one needs to argue the existence of $g$. This can be done by invoking Urysohn Lemma in general topology.